# less -+Option documentation

Tags: linux, less, documentation

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12499930/258418) `less -+S` is used, to toggle the `-S` option off.

I am wondering where this behaviour of less is documented, as scrolling `less --help` only yields `+cmd                 Execute the less cmd each time a new file is examined.` which does not seem to explain the `-+S` option syntax. Where is this syntax documented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found this in [`man 1 less`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/less), "Commands" section [emphasis mine]:

> `-+`
>   Followed by one of the command line option letters this will reset the option to its default setting and print a message describing the new setting. (**The `-+X` command does the same thing as `-+X` on the command line.**) This does not work for string-valued options.

It describes the general syntax for some commands (i.e. what you can type when `less` is running), but also states the same syntax works on the command line.